# Loading a raw File from Resource

Tags: c++, file, winapi, file-io, resources

Whats the easiest way to load a raw file from a resource in C++ using the WinAPI?
I just want to load the file(for example .txt) into a char array. I searched on the internet but I couldn't really find something useful and simple like LoadStringFromFile(int idFromResource, char* buffer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the following steps:

1. Call [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx) passing module handle, resource type and resource name. This yields a `HRSRC`. Note that if you have a resource ID rather than a resource name, use [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648029.aspx) to convert.
2. Call [`LoadResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046.aspx) passing the `HRSRC` from the previous step. This yields an `HGLOBAL`.
3. Call [`LockResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047.aspx) passing the `HGLOBAL`. This yields a pointer to the first byte of the resource.
4. Call [`SizeofResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048.aspx) passing the `HRSRC` to find the size of the resource.
5. Copy the content of the resource into your buffer using the pointer retrieved from step 3, and the size retrieved from step 4.

Comment: Is this possible using the resource id instead of the filename?

Comment: See here (the RCDATA resource type)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381039(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user3075425 You use the [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648029.aspx) macro for that. The docs for [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx) do cover that.

Comment: Whats the best way to copy the HGLOBAL? I casted it to a char array, but this char array was empty then.

Comment: Call LockResource to get a pointer. Then std::memcpy for example.